# php category title not showing

Tags: php

I am creating PHP category page my script not showing # mark and + mark added category title example like this my [URL Localhost](http://localhost/zblog/category/1/1/c#).

http://localhost/zblog/category/1/2/c++ and also my other title added category opening like this http://localhost/zblog/category/1/3/php

Here is my code

```
if(isset($_GET['srcid'])) {
$srcid = $_GET['srcid'];
$title= $_GET['title'];
}
```

category link

```
<span class="post-category"><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>
category/1/<?php echo $row['cat_id']  ?>/
<?php echo $row['cat_title']; ?>" title="View all posts in General" rel="category tag">
<?php echo $row['cat_title']; ?></a></span>
```

url link

```
 <a class="post-source" href="<?php echo $url; ?>
<?php echo 'category/'.rawurlencode($row['cat_id']).'/'.
rawurlencode($row['cat_title']);?>"><h1 class="post-title">
<?php echo $row['cat_title']  ?></h1></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#` is an unsafe url character because it has meaning in a URL. It's referred to as a `fragment` and is used with link anchors.

`+` is a safe character, and there should be no reason why it would not work.

I would recommend you try parsing your URL's differently.

```php
$url = 'http://localhost/zblog/category/1/2/c++';
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$categories = explode("/", str_replace("/zblog/category/", "", $path));

var_dump($categories);
```

Output:

```sh
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "c++"
}
```

Comment: Using non-URL safe characters is always a problem and accommodating them can be nothing but trouble as some proxies might reject them.

Answer (score 0):

You are preparing your link in the wrong way for PHP. Also, you need to ecnode special characters for sending through URL. For PHP to interpret URL properly and to get values from it, you need to do it like this:

```
<span class="post-category"><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>?srcid=<?php echo 'category/1/'.rawurlencode($row['cat_id']).'/';  ?>&title=<?php echo rawurlencode($row['cat_title']); ?>" title="View all posts in General" rel="category tag">
```

This is an example of how to create a PHP link:

```
http://web_adress/page.php?first_param=value_of_first_param&second_param=value_of_second_param&third_param=value_of_third_param
                          ^                                ^                                  ^
                          Here you start with params       Here you are telling the other one is coming
```

then you can use:

```
if(isset($_GET['first_param']) {
  //Get all others or whatever
  $second_param = rawurldecode($_GET['second_param']);

  //Your example
  $srcid = rawurldecode($_GET['srcid']);
  $title = rawurldecode($_GET['title']);
}
```

If you can adjust your code to the example I have created here it will work. To be able to send special characters through URL use `rawurlencode` to encode these characters and on the other end, you use `rawurldecode` to decode them. I made an example above. Please note, if you use `urlencode` + sign will not go through, and you will get space.

Comment: i added but same results my problem is php,html,css like category opening but c# c++ like category not opening

Comment: I've updated my answer. I've added encoding for special characters.

Comment: I changed it but same results

Comment: Any errors? How does your link displays now? Can you update your code so I can take a look and find a problem?

Comment: my c# category url display like this http://localhost/zblog/category/1/1/c%23 but not showing

Comment: Ok, can you update how you prepare your url now? And echo $cat_title so we can see the values retrieved?

Comment: I added my url link my url display php html css like category but not showing c# C++ like category

Comment: URL is still not formed well so your variables `$cat_id` and `$cat_title` are empty. Use this link `<a class="post-source" href="<?php echo $url; ?>?cat_id=
<?php echo 'category/.rawurlencode($row['cat_id']).'/'; ?>&cat_title=<?php
rawurlencode($row['cat_title']);?>"><h1 class="post-title">
<?php echo $row['cat_title']  ?></h1></a> ` On category view page do this `var_dump($cat_id)` and var_dump($cat_title)`. This will output what came through the URL so we are sure we get proper values. I think you will not be able to send `$cat_id` directly to SQL without formating it for query.

Comment: I have added htaccess file to change url